# Importing GPS coordintates in Decimal Degrees with N and S at the end instead of + or -

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv, import

I have a CSV file with GPS coordinates formated in decimal degrees. Instead of using negative symbols for south hemisphere and east of the prime meridian coordinates some of the coordinates shows a N or S, E or W letter after the decimal degrees. QGIS is only plotting XY coordinates without letter characters. Any idea how to have QGIS recognize both formats?

Comment: Don't know if QGIS "import from gps" dialog lets you choose for the N-W case; maybe just try replacing on other software before importing (R, spreadsheets), or import through python console

Comment: You have an option in QGIS to import a CSV file (Layer-->Add layer -->  Delimited Text) and then check `DMS coordinates`, this should work for coordinates formatted with degree, minutes, and seconds. Alternatively, if it's *only* the letter then you could use a simple field calculator to edit this field. Can you provide an example of your dataset in the question (first 10 records) or so?